# Should I set my optional parameters default as false or true

Tags: javascript, php, parameters, default, optional-parameters

While writing new functions everybody once and a while adds some optional parameters to functions.

Normally I evaluate how often I would need to change a parameter (considering my use cases) and set the default value in a way that represents the most-often-used combination of parameters.
I would not care if the default value therefore is `false` or `true` or `null`. In PHP if you don't use a parameter, you just ommit it in the code.

So a function

```
public function getUrl($absolute = true)
```

could give me, based on whether or not `$absolute` is set to true, the absolute or relative path of a URL. If I do need the absolute path, I call it like `getUrl()`, if I need the relative path, I call it `getUrl(false)`.

I could, however, change the definition of the function to

```
public function getUrl($relative = false)
```

Changing the way the function is called only when I need the path relative to `getUrl(true)`.

Personally, I think in PHP it does not make much of a difference, although I prefer to "set" extra parameters, instead of "unsetting" them. Maybe that's just my opinion.

In VueJS Components however, it does make more of a difference. I could create a component that renders a text and a button, and add a property to decide whether or not it should show the button (for whatever reason).
If I would say by default the button is shown, there are two ways to go here.

1) Have a property `showButton` that defaults to `true`.

2) Have a property `hideButton` that defaults to `false`.

Both would do practically the same, but the difference in calling them when I want my button hidden is:

1) `<text-button-component :showButton="false" />`

vs

2) `<text-button-component hide-button />`

Since I worked a lot with Vue.js recently, I now tend to always have my optional parameters' default value set to false and only "set" optional parameters, instead of "unsetting" them.

Is there a best-practice around this behavior? A common understanding? Or is it just personal preference?

Comment: 3) Avoid boolean flags and use more expressive values instead. E.g. `$getUrl($style = ABSOLUTE)`.

Comment: Surely it depends on the parameter? If you're using dependency injection then you'd be passing an object as the parameter - in which case the logical *default* value would be `null` as `true/false` wouldn't be valid for that type: e.g. `getWidget(WidgetConfig $config = null) { ... }`